# Dominant wavelength calculator from chromaticity coordinates

Tags: c#, colors

is there any function, or library, preferably in c#, that could calculate the dominant wavelength of a color, using ONLY the x and y coordinates as input?
I have learned how the process goes, that you need to draw a line from the white point (0.33, 0.33), through my point to the violet edge, and that interception is the dominant wavelength, but all the libraries I have found require that the interception coordinates are already calculated.
If someone can please give me a library, or piece of code, how to calculate the dominant wavelength using ONLY the x and y coordinates I would be extremely grateful.

[image]

Comment: We have a reference Python implementation here: https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/develop/colour.colorimetry.html#dominant-wavelength-and-purity, https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/develop/colour/colorimetry/dominant.py

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately these functions also require the intersect coordinates. I am really amazed how nobody has made a function for this (calculating the intersect coordinates).

Comment: No, the parameters are only the chromaticity of interest and that of the whitepoint, e.g. E (0.333, 0.333), the intersection is computed automatically.

Comment: Kel Solaar did it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unicolour](https://github.com/waacton/Unicolour), a colour library for I've developed for .NET, has recently been updated with this functionality.

```cs
var chromaticity = new Chromaticity(0.1, 0.8);
var hyperGreen = new Unicolour(chromaticity);
var dominantWavelength = hyperGreen.DominantWavelength;
```

It calculates the intercept coordinates for you, though since it's open source you can see how it works by looking at the `Spectral` class.

Comment: Thank you! I already implemented the python solution, I wish I had this 3 months ago :D but for someone having the same problem, this library is definitely the c# solution.